# Wait properties windows dialog before continue script

Tags: c#

I had a piece of code to display the properties window of a file,

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\Users\nyongrand\Desktop\Internet Download Manager.lnk";
psi.Verb = "properties";
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit(); //This give me exception, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

what I want is to wait until the window properties is closed, because if my code closed the properties window will be closed as well, I need a solution between, my code is able to wait for the properties window closed, or my code can exit without closing the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting means that `process` is `null` at the time you try to call its `WaitForExit` member method. So the question you should be asking is why.

Start with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) for the overload of the `Process.Start` function that you're calling to see what it actually returns. Sure enough, it returns a `Process` object, but only under certain conditions:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.Diagnostics.Process`
>   A new `Process` component that is associated with the process resource, or `null` if no process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).

And, from the "Remarks" section:

> **Note:** If the address of the executable file to start is a URL, the process is not started and `null` is returned.

So, if an existing process is re-used, the `Process.Start` method will return `null`. And you cannot call methods on `null`.

Comment: Okay, I missed that one when I was going through the documentation.  Nicely written.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Process process = Process.Start(psi);
```

with

```
Process process = new Process();

if(process.Start(psi))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
else
{
    //Do something here to handle your process failing to start
}
```

The problem you face with your code is that [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) returns a Boolean.  It's not a factory for Process objects.